# WP Как удалить все нужные postmeta поля при отключении плагина

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Есть такая задача, что при удалении плагина WordPress он должен почистить все поля в таблице `wp_postmeta` с `meta_key`  LIKE `positive_users_reaction` и `meta_key` LIKE `negative_users_reaction`. Пишу вот такой код в файле `uninstall.php`

```
global $wpdb;

defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN') || exit;
$table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'postmeta';
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ${table_name} WHERE `meta_key` LIKE `positive_users_reaction` AND  LIKE `negative_users_reaction` ;");
```

Но он не отрабатываете, подскажите, пожалуйста в чем ошибка ?

Comment: А зачем Вам `LIKE`, если Вы указываете полное название ключа? `table_name` можно заменить на `$wpdb->postmeta`. Перед вторым LIKE нужно указать что именно у Вас будет `LIKE`, в Вашем случае это опять же `meta_key`. Ну и это не джеес, вот это работать не будет `${table_name}`, замените на `{$table_name}`, а еще лучше на `{$wpdb->postmeta}`, но вообще без фигурных скобок тоже будет работать.

Comment: $table_name мне нужен, поскольку мы не знаем какой префикс поставит тот, кто будет инсталлировать плагин. Это на всякий случай. Но оно у меня и с просто `wp_postmeta` чего-то не отрабатывает(

Comment: `$wpdb->postmeta` вернет верное название таблицы с верным префиксом, вне зависимости от того, какой префикс таблиц будет задан при установке WordPress, не переживайте. Не отрабатывает, как минимум по вышеописанным причинам) Но Вы бы попробовали сделать сам запрос в phpMyAdmin, например, Вам покажет какие ошибки есть в запросе.

Comment: И замените `AND` на `OR`.

Comment: ` DELETE * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE `positive_users_reaction` OR WHERE `meta_key` LIKE `negative_users_reaction`  ` Неожиданное ключевое слово. (near "WHERE" at position 79), это на 2-е `WHERE` . А без него  #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '* FROM ... Это просто если удалять один элемент.

Comment: `"DELETE FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key LIKE 'positive_users_reaction' OR meta_key LIKE 'negative_users_reaction'"`, двух `WHERE` в одном запросе быть не может. Ну и при удалении `*` не нужна, так как Вы удаляете row, это не SELECT запрос, где Вы выбираете нужные колонки.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Так сработало.

Comment: Явная ошибка - использование неправильной кавычки. В MySQL каждый тип кавычки используется для строго определённых целей, нельзя использовать что под руку подвернулось. Логическая ошибка - оператор AND, ибо полученное выражение требует, чтобы одно значение поля равнялось/соответствовало двум разным значениям. Ну а LIKE вместо очевидного знака равенства - это так, вишенка.